Have a Repository Method Analyze Multiple Tables
In building complex calls with the repository pattern for the first time, I'm researching best practices.
The response in this post Having a repository dependent on another repository seems to suggest that we cannot reference other repositories.
Fine. Makes sense.
Any issue with referencing other tables from the Entity Framework context within a repository method? Such as the Users within the ProjectRepository in the example method below? Or is there a better pattern:
internal class ProjectRepository : Repository<Project>, IProjectRepository
    {
        public __GlobalDbContext GlobalDbContext
        { 
            get { return Context as __GlonalDBContext; } 
        }

    public ProjectRepository(__GlonalDBContext context) : base(context) { }

  public IEnumerable<Project> GetProjectsWithUsers()
    {
        List<Guid?> us = GlobalDbContext.Users.Select(u => u.ProjectGuid).ToList();
        return GlobalDbContext.Projects.Where(p => us.Contains(p.ProjectGuid));
    }
}


If you aren't exposing other entities directly it's not that big of a deal. However, EF DbSets are already repositories.

I'm following the James Montemagno repository pattern.

If you're using EF, you're already using a repository pattern.  Why add another on top?

Don't use a design pattern just for the sake of it. As @DavidBrowne-Microsoft noted, EF is a framework that follows the repository pattern (among others). If you follow a pattern without knowing why, you'll get it wrong and you'll also lose a primary benefit of design patterns: they are well known idioms that other programmers will recognize.

My repository pattern is fine. It works for us. These comments don't address the question.
